# Automapper does not map inherited Dictionary

Tags: c#, automapper

So I have the following classes:

```
public class RemoteAgent : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public string testMappingNormalAttr { get; set;}
    public string RemoteAgentMethod(){
        return "notUsed";
    }
}

public class MySystem : Dictionary<string, string>
{
    public string testMappingNormalAttr { get; set;}
    public string MySystemMethod(){
        return "notUsed";
    }
}
```

And would like to map the dictionary and the property of `RemoteAgent` to `MySystem`. So I create the following main class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using AutoMapper;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<RemoteAgent, MySystem>();
        }
        );
        RemoteAgent remAge = new RemoteAgent();
        remAge.Add("testString","one");
        remAge.Add("testString2","two");
        remAge.testMappingNormalAttr = "normalAttr";
        var res = Mapper.Map(remAge,typeof(RemoteAgent),typeof(MySystem));
    }
}
```

The thing is, `res` contains the `testMappingNormalAttr` property, so mapping the property was successful, but not the keys and values of the dictionary in `remAge`. The dictionary inside `res` is empty, while I expected the dictionary entries I added to `remAge` using `Add()` to be in `res`. What am I missing here? I am using Automapper 8.0.0.

Comment: You can auto map smth as a collection or as a class, but not both at the same time. You can work around it with `AfterMap`.

Comment: But the underlying issue here is that you're inheriting from `Dictionary`. You should just have a `Dictionary` member. Cleaner design and the problem goes away.